# Loading xib in Landscape Project is showed with Portrait dimensions in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode9

Project in Landscape orientation. With the new Xcode 9, loading a xib assign Portrait dimesions to the xib view, even when app is Landscape.

It happens in ios 11 and 10, and only in XCode 9, not in previous

Comment: Got the same issue with one of my old projects which doesn't apply autolayout